# Combining sql select and Count

Tags: sql, count

I have two tables

A  and  B

```
 A                          B
-----------------         -----------------
a_pk (int)                b_pk (int)
a_name(varchar)           a_pk (int)
                          b_name (varchar)
```

I could write a query

```
SELECT a.a_name, b.b_name
FROM  a LEFT OUTER JOIN b ON a.a_pk = b.a_pk
```

and this would return me a non distinct list of everything in table a and its table b joined data. Duplicates would display for column a where different b records shared a common a_pk column value.

But what I want to do is get a full list of values from table A column a_name   and ADD a column that is a COUNT of the joined values of table B.

So if a_pk  = 1  and a_name = test   and in table b there are 5 records that have a a_pk value of 1  my result set would be

```
a_name        b_count
------        -------
test           5
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The query should like this :

```
SELECT 
    a.a_name, 
    (
        SELECT Count(b.b_pk) 
        FROM b 
        Where b.a_pk = a.a_pk
    ) as b_count 
FROM  a
```

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT a_name, COUNT(*) as 'b_count'
FROM 
    A a
    JOIN B b
    ON a.a_pk = b.a_pk
GROUP BY a_name
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
    a.name,
    (
        SELECT COUNT(1)
        FROM B b
        WHERE b.a_pk = a.a_pk
    )
FROM A a
```